# Enforcing to supply a completion block

Tags: objective-c, standards, objective-c-blocks

I'm wondering about whether or not this is good practice:

I have a method that takes in parameters and a callback block, let's say something along the lines of:

```
-(void)loginWithUsername:(NSString *)username andPassword:(NSString *)password withCompletion:(LoginManagerCompletionBlock)completionHandler;
```

Now in this specific case, there is no use in calling this method without a completion handler, as it triggers a redundant call to a login web service (also, it does not change the state of anything - not client side nor server side). I would like to avoid these situations by actively enforcing the requirement of passing me a completion block in order to make this web service call. I sort of think of this as a "@required" method in an Objective C protocol. So my questions are:

1. Is requiring a completion block in order to perform an action good practice in Objective C?
2. (Edit: Answered) How do I enforce this requirement? Is there built-in language syntax that can help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: interesting question. In Android Java one can use the @NotNull attribute, would be good to have something similar in Obj-C

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the function attribute `nonnull(params)`, where *params* is 1 or more comma-separated parameter numbers, to indicate that a parameter should not be null (`nonnull` without parentheses means all pointer parameters should not be null). For your example:

```
- (void) loginWithUsername:(NSString *)username
               andPassword:(NSString *)password
            withCompletion:(LoginManagerCompletionBlock)completionHandler
                           __attribute__((nonnull(3)));
```

**However**, while this is a compile time check and produces a warning it will only do so if null is passed directly. If the argument value is an expression which evaluates to null, e.g. a variable with a null value, then this will not be caught.

If a parameter being null is an error you can add a runtime check within the method itself using `NSParameterAssert(parameter)`, where *parameter* is the name of one of the method's parameters, to check for this condition. This call is defined to print an error message and throw an exception if its argument evaluates to false, and null evaluates to false.

Comment: This is wonderful :) Is there anything else you can add about this being good/bad practice?

Comment: @Stavash - Well it is good practice to document if a parameter should be non-null, and the attribute does that and provides (albeit limited) enforcement. However at runtime if possible a soft error is probably better than throwing an exception as `NSParameterAssert` does; but that is a subjective opinion!

Comment: I agree that documentation in this case is good practice - but the general matter still remains unanswered - as a rule, would it be good/bad practice to stop carrying out an operation if completion code was not supplied?

Comment: @stavash In development, always NSParameterAssert. In production, you have to choose between crashing to avoid undefined behaviour or continue to provide a better user experience. The choice depends on the consequences for your particular application, there is no general rule.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what `NSParameterAssert` is for. Use it to check that parameters aren't nil.

```
NSParameterAssert( completionParameter );
```

Though, in this specific case, it's probably best to log the completion handler being nil and return. There is no point doing any additional work. You probably want the assertion during development to make it obvious that you have an issue that needs to be resolved.

Comment: Thanks @Wain - I guess that this assertion is done at runtime, right? Is there a compile time flag I can use to enforce this?

Comment: Yes, it is a runtime check.